# Is there way to update an entity properties and add a reference to it through one single PATCH-request in OData v4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, odata

In context of the WCFService with the OData v2 support, I was able to perform a [single MERGE request which will change property values of the entity and the references owned by it (through the __metadata object of the request payload)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13690535/492641).

[I've read about $ref requests in OData v4 and CreateRef technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377962/updating-navigation-property-in-odata-webapi), but it will cost two requests. One to change property values of the entity and the other one to change entity references.

Is there a way to patch an entity and edit its references in one single request in WebAPI with the OData v4 support?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 1:n relation you can easily set the foreign key in the request. However your Model must provide a link to the foreign key. Here is an example model (code first):

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ManagerId")]
    public Person Manager { get; set; }
}
```

In an m:n relation this is not possible because of it's design (EF automatically create a relation table.). However, you can use a custom action an implement the relationship building on your own.